# Blog Plugin in zend framework 1.11.7

Tags: zend-framework

I want to use blog plugin in zend framework 1.11.7. So please give me the full path from where I can download plugin and all the steps to implement in site.

Comment: Blog Plugin ? ZF is not a wordpress-kind system to apply plugins on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.

There are, however, plenty of tutorials to help you get started with *building* one. http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/